# How to enable ngx_stream_core_module in Yocto

Tags: nginx, yocto

I tried to enable ngx_stream_core_module by adding following code in nginx.inc

```
do_configure () {
--with-stream=dynamic
}

FILES_${PN} += "${PN}/*"
SYSROOT_DIRS += "${PN}/"
```

but compiling error happens,
nginx: Files/directories were installed but not shipped in any package:
  /usr/modules/ngx_stream_module.so

and I am sure ngx_stream_module.so is generated in nginx/1.12.2-r0/package/usr/modules/.

Can anyone give me some ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `FILES_${PN}` you should reference the installation path of the installed files and the files themselves (the latter can be substituted by a wildcard) within a package. As follows:

```
FILES_${PN} += "/usr/modules/*"
```

Check out https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-FILES

Furthermore, you should point out to the YP version you're using, as well as the meta-layer that contains your nginx recipe.

PD: It is a bad practice to modify the *.inc or the *.bb of a recipe from a third party layer, write a *.bbappend on your own layer instead.