# How to install nginx on yocto project

Tags: nginx, yocto, yocto-recipe

My Yocto project version

"3.1.15"

I do find nginx under the follow directory

```
meta-openembedded/meta-webserver/recipes-httpd/nginx
├── files
│   ├── 0001-Allow-the-overriding-of-the-endianness-via-the-confi.patch
│   ├── CVE-2021-23017.patch
│   ├── CVE-2021-3618.patch
│   ├── default_server.site
│   ├── nginx.conf
│   ├── nginx-cross.patch
│   ├── nginx-fix-pidfile.patch
│   ├── nginx.init
│   ├── nginx.service
│   ├── nginx-volatile.conf
│   └── proxy_params
├── nginx_1.16.1.bb
├── nginx_1.17.8.bb
└── nginx.inc
```

I have tried to add

```
IMAGE_INSTALL += "nginx"
```

under `build\conf\local.conf`
but it shows error

```
ERROR: Nothing RPROVIDES 'nginx' 
NOTE: Runtime target 'nginx' is unbuildable, removing...
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['nginx']
ERROR: Required build target 'rity-demo-image' has no buildable providers.
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['rity-demo-image', 'nginx']
```

I have read  one of the article
[How to enable ngx_stream_core_module in Yocto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55796899/how-to-enable-ngx-stream-core-module-in-yocto/55805399#55805399)

It says that

```
PD: It is a bad practice to modify the *.inc or the *.bb of a recipe from a third party layer, write a *.bbappend on your own layer instead.
```

Why?
and What should I do next if I want to correctly install nginx

Comment: 1. Have you added `meta-openembedded/meta-webserver` to your layers in `bblayers.conf`? 2. Changing 3rd party layers is considered a bad practice, because when the 3rd party layer is updated it might delete (or conflict with) your edits. Having your changes in bbappend in your own layer gives a clear separation, and makes updates in general safer. Distributing your own changes gets easier in your own layer too.

Comment: @skandigraun Thanks for the reply. You are correct! I forgot to check the  bblayers.conf after adding into it now i can correctly install nginx(1.16.1) but now I have a new question. I would like to install a newer version of nginx (1.24.0) How am i going to accomplish that

Comment: The easiest is to borrow the recipe from [meta-oe](https://github.com/openembedded/meta-openembedded/tree/d7d987e01d5d0fde40ebe41d4bc10bf70e1604d4/meta-webserver/recipes-httpd/nginx), add it to your layer, and add `PREFERRED_VERSION_nginx = "1.24.0"` to `local.conf` to ensure the correct version if built.

Comment: @skandigraun Thanks for the help . After following your guide  copy those file from  
 [meta-oe](https://github.com/openembedded/meta-openembedded/tree/d7d987e01d5d0fde40ebe41d4bc10bf70e1604d4/meta-webserver/recipes-httpd/nginx)  ,  I have successfully install  nginx (1.24.0) and looks like it works well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to check the bblayers.conf after adding into it now i can correctly install nginx(1.16.1)

```
${YOCTOROOT}/src/poky/../meta-openembedded/meta-webserver \
```