# trying to extend Recipe using BBCLASSEXTEND = "nginx" but failed

Tags: nginx, yocto, yocto-recipe

[How to install nginx on yocto project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77078694/how-to-install-nginx-on-yocto-project)

So After correctly install nginx on yocto

Now I am trying to write my own recipe to replace the default_server which I modified
while using BBCLASSEXTEND = "nginx"

/etc/nginx/sites-available/default_server

```
SUMMARY = "nginxconfig"

DESCRIPTION = "${SUMMARY}"

LICENSE = "CLOSED"

LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "mychecksum"

S = "${WORKDIR}"

BBCLASSEXTEND = "nginx"

SRC_URI = " \
            file://default_server \ 
            "





do_install() {
    install -d ${D}/etc/nginx/sites-available
   
    cp -f ${WORKDIR}/default_server ${D}/etc/nginx/sites-available/
    

}


FILES_${PN} += "/etc/nginx/sites-available/* "
```

However it shows error

```
/meta-wmt/recipes-wmt/nginxconfig/nginxconfig.bb: 
Could not inherit file classes/nginx.bbclassA
```

So what did I miss here I am pretty sure nginx is exist

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Based on the recipe you posted, you are trying to extend the original nginx recipe, but for that you should just create a `bbappend` file, and no need to touch `BBCLASSEXTEND` at all.

Comment: Thanks for the early reply. What im trying to do is I found out that `nginx.bb` will create `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default_server` and I would like to replace it to my own modified `"default_server"` So I create a new recipe called `nginxconfig.bb` and  try to accomplish the goal but found out that  it did not replace the file. So after doing some research I thought `BBCLASSEXTEND` can help me out to fix the problem directly replace the file under `tmp\work\aarch64-poky-linux\nginx\1.24.0-r0\package\etc\nginx\sites-available\default_server` or maybe there is a better way ?

Comment: Yes. BBCLASSEXTEND is for a totally different thing. Create a bbappend called the same name as the original recipe, or with a wildcard (e.g. `nginx_%.bbappend`). When you build nginx, this file will be appended automatically to the original recipe. Use `SRC_URI +=` instead of `SRC_URI =` and use `do_install:append()` instead of `do_install()` to extend the original recipe instead of completely overriding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BBCLASSEXTEND` has nothing to do with what you are trying to accomplish.

In order to override a file that another recipe is providing, the only solution is to override the original process of installing that file which is `do_install` of the original `nginx` recipe.

You do that by creating a `bbappend` file to `nginx`: `nginx_%.bbappend`.

**[NOTE]** If your file is related to only a specific version of `nginx` then specify the version in the `bbappend` file name.

Now, you should have this path:

```
meta-wmt
   | recipes-httpd
        | nginx
            | nginx_%.bbappend
            | files
                | default_server.site
```

Make note that the original `nginx` recipe has the file named: `default_server.site`, so name your file the same exact name. Keep reading you will know why.

The `nginx_%.bbappend` file is with the following content only:

```bash
FILESEXTRAPATHS:prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"
```

The trick here is that the original recipe will try to find `default_server.site` in `FILESEXTRAPATHS` and as you can see we did a `prepend` on it, so the new path that contains your custom `default_server.site` will be the first path it will search in, so it will grab your custom file instead.